# How to write XLSX to XML using Column name as tag

Tags: python, xml, xlsx

I have a Python file in which I take the content of an Excel file and import the data into a XML File.

This is the result-content of my XML-File:

```
 <A1>User_ID</A1>
 <B1>Name</B1>
 <C1>Age</C1>
 <D1>Country</D1>
 <A2>1</A2>
 <B2>Thomas</B2>
      ...
```

This is my Python File:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import xlrd
from lxml import etree 
from xml.dom import minidom


root = etree.Element('onlv')
root.set('xmlns', 'http://www.oenorm.at/schema/A2063/2009-06-01')
root.set('xmlns_xsi', 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance')
root.set('xsi_schemaLocation', 'http://www.oenorm.at/schema/A2063/2009-06-01 onlv.xsd')
root.set('xmlns_on', 'http://www.oenorm.at/schema/A2063/2009-06-01')
tree = etree.ElementTree(root)

wb = load_workbook('test3.xlsx')
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Tabelle1')


def prettify(xmlStr):
    INDENT = "       "
    rough_string = etree.tostring(xmlStr)
    reparsed = minidom.parseString(rough_string)
    return reparsed.toprettyxml(indent=INDENT)


for rowOfCellObjects in sheet.rows:


    for cellObj in rowOfCellObjects:

        datatype = type(cellObj.value)

        if(datatype is str): 
            etree.SubElement(root, cellObj.coordinate).text = cellObj.value

        elif(datatype is int): 
            etree.SubElement(root, cellObj.coordinate).text = str(int(cellObj.value))



        else:
            pass        


tree.write("filename3.xml", encoding="utf-8", pretty_print=True, xml_declaration = True) 

prettified_xmlStr = prettify(tree)
output_file = open("filename3.xml", "w")
output_file.write(prettified_xmlStr)
output_file.close()
```

My problem is that I don't want the cells `A1`, `B1`, `C1` etc. to be in the `<>` marks.
But instead I want the content of `row 1` and `column A` to be in the `<>` marks.

So that the program starts with `row 1 column A`, then `row 1 column B` and so on.  For example:

```
<User_ID> 1 </User_ID>
<Name> Thomas </Name>
<Age> 34 </Age>
<Country> Germany </Country>
<User_ID> 2 </User_ID>
<Name> James </Name>
<Age> 23 </Age>
<Country> USA </Country>
         ....
```

If the excel-file looks like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUmZz.png)

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: The code is not complete. Make sure that we can reproduce the issue by providing a [mcve]. Don't describe the expected XML output, please **show us** exactly what it should look like.

Comment: Read about [isinstance](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance).

Comment: @mccutter: Yes that makes sense, it's simple a record per line using the headers value as `<...>` and column values. You have to group every line for simpler reading, e.g.: `<DATA><Record><User_ID>1</User_ID><Name>...</Record></DATA>`

Comment: @stovfl, sorry I don't get what you exactly mean

Comment: @mccutter: You have to do: `.SubElement(record, header_value_for_this_column).text = column.value`. Where `record = .SubElement(root, '<Record>')`

Comment: @stovfl, so instead of writing `etree.SubElement(root, cellObj.coordinate).text = cellObj.value` I write: `etree.SubElemen(record, header_value_for_this_column).text = column.value` ? and in the next row at "elif" too?

Comment: @mccutter: Yes. You can do general: `.text = str(column.value)`, no `elif ...` needed.

Comment: @stovfl, hmm so I don't need if statements at all ? First I have to define "column" or not? Because the program does not know what column is.. Sorry for asking so many questions, I am bit confused how to implement those things..

Comment: @mccutter: ***"define `column`"***: `column` is your `cellObj`.

Comment: @stovfl, ok so I can replacce cellObj with column without problems? And what do I write instead of '<Record'>?

Comment: @mccutter: ***"instead of '<Record'>"***: My bad, use the string `Record` as is.